# Uses for Sycamore tree bark?

Tags: recycling, trees

I live near a number of parks which have very large Sycamore trees. In winter these trees naturally shed their bark.

[image]

The bark tends to pile up at the bottom of the tree until, I assume, the park maintanance crew clears it up.

It seems like such a shame to let it go to waste. **Does this bark have any particular uses?** I guess using it as a light form of firewood might work.

Or perhaps it's better for the environment to just leave it where it is?

Comment: It could be used as mulch in gardens to conserve moisture.